# Integration Unity (vuforia Library) with an Objective-C iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, unity-game-engine

I am integrating Unity in an iOS app and am following [this link](https://the-nerd.be/2014/08/06/add-unity3d-in-a-native-ios-application/). My app is compiled fine and linking good, but once it's installing it's show me this error:

[image: Please view this image].

I also read [this link as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40283628/unity-application-crashes-at-ios-due-to-shader-not-compiled), but I think my error is different. I am also attaching the log as well:

[image: Please view log file]

Comment: Shader code compilation failed, usage of undeclared identifier

Comment: can you guide me a little bit because I am not unity developer so i can guide my unity fellow.actually he is new an dont have any clue.