# Unity - iOS: WARNING: Shader Unsupported: 'Hidden/BlitToDepth'

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, shader

I'm making a 2D game using Unity, i exported the game to Android and it runs smoothly with no problems, i exported the same game to Xcode and then i installed the game on my iPhone, it doesn't crash but the log gives me those warning:

```
GfxDevice: creating device client; threaded=1
Initializing Metal device caps: Apple A11 GPU
Initialize engine version: 2017.3.1f1 (fc1d3344e6ea)
WARNING: Shader Unsupported: 'Hidden/BlitToDepth' - Pass '' has no 
vertex shader
WARNING: Shader Unsupported: 'Hidden/BlitToDepth' - Setting to default 
shader.
WARNING: Shader Unsupported: 'Hidden/BlitToDepth_MSAA' - Pass '' has no 
vertex shader
WARNING: Shader Unsupported: 'Hidden/BlitToDepth_MSAA' - Setting to 
default shader.
Setting up 1 worker threads for Enlighten.
.....
...
```

And the movement in the game is a little bit laggy. (but on Android devices the movement is smooth)

I searched all over the internet and i tried every solution there is. Nothing seems to work.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT**
I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40283628/unity-application-crashes-on-ios-due-to-shader-not-compiled) but it didn't work.

**EDIT2** 
Unity [says](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/ios-vr-vr-shaders-are-included-in-builds-even-though-vr-support-is-disabled) that this is a bug and the problem is resolved, i don't see the solution!.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?